# HTML&CSS + Twitter Bootstrap: add error message after Angular validation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

We need add error message on `Phone`, `Name`, and `Firstname` field if a validation field need display this error.

if one error is present on name, only name error is display and all align do not change.

```
  +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |  Title                                                              | button | |
  +------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |  Phone | input |    Name | input |    Firstname | input |           | button | |
  |  error phone        error name        error firstname                          |
  +------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |  Content table                                                                 |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  |                                                                                |
  +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <form class="form-inline w-100 d-flex">
    <div class="form-group mr-4">
      <label for="field-1"class="mr-2">Field #1</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="field-1">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mr-4">
      <label for="field-2"class="mr-2">Field #2</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="field-2">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-success ml-auto">Button</button>
  </form>
</nav>
```

**EDIT**

My angular validation is OK. I want add this in desing via bootstrap:

```
<div id="invalid-name-message" *ngIf="(f.lastname.errors?.maxlength || f.lastname.errors?.pattern) && (f.lastname.dirty || f.lastname.touched)" class="invalid-feedback d-block">{{ 'LASTNAME_INVALID' | translate }}</div>
```

live example on https://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/5svek2xn/

Comment: Have you checked custom validators at https://angular.io/guide/form-validation ?

Comment: My validation is OK, my question is only on the desing

Comment: Could you add errors in your jsfiddle for example ?

Comment: `<div>error...</div>`   https://jsfiddle.net/ht8dsgz5/2/

Comment: Check out my edited answer when you'll be available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set your `form-group` element to `flex-shrink-1` and if you need to, add the class `flex-nowrap` to your `<form>`. For more information check out the [flex documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/) of Boostrap 4.

https://jsfiddle.net/xn6qh3t2/

Other solution, the better one IMO, wrap your `<label>` and `<input>` in a flex container (`<div class="d-flex"></div>`) and add these classes  `.flex-column` and `.align-items-start` to `<div class="form-group">`.

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <form class="form-inline w-100 d-flex flex-nowrap">
    <div class="form-group mr-4 flex-column align-items-start">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <label for="field-1" class="mr-2">Field #1</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="field-1">
      </div>
      <div id="invalid-name-message" *ngIf="(f.lastname.errors?.maxlength || f.lastname.errors?.pattern) && (f.lastname.dirty || f.lastname.touched)" class="invalid-feedback d-block">{{ 'LASTNAME_INVALID' | translate }}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mr-4 flex-column align-items-start">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <label for="field-2" class="mr-2">Field #2</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="field-2">
        </div>
      <div id="invalid-name-message" *ngIf="(f.lastname.errors?.maxlength || f.lastname.errors?.pattern) && (f.lastname.dirty || f.lastname.touched)" class="invalid-feedback d-block">{{ 'LASTNAME_INVALID' | translate }}</div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success ml-auto">Button</button>

  </form>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cL7nr5o6/